# "No suitable application records were found" error on AppStore

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

I'm trying to upload my app to AppStore but it gives me the next error:

```
No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier
```

I've checked both them in my Xcode and in my iTunesConnect profile, the identifiers are the same, but I still get this error. I do not understand why I get this error. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Check whether  you have used capital letter and small letters in xcode's bundle id in both cases.

Comment: No, I've copied from the Xcode and pasted it in iTunes Connect. So, they are the same @UmaMadhavi